# member function erase() not working in a loop

Tags: c++, string, loops, erase

I'm programming a little game; but stringname.erase() seems to be not working in a 'for-loop' , I want to understand why, I have other alternatives, but I don't understand what's going on in the following code.

**More explications of my situation (*Important!)*:**

guess is a char.
'tmgword' and 'word' are of type string, and: tmgword = word ;

what I understand from my code:

in the first time,the 'while'-loop verifies if there is 'guess' in the string 'tmpgword'. 
 That is true and the for-loop is working fine, the right character(guess) that verifies the if-condition is erased.

in the second time: the 'while'-loop verifies again if there is 'guess' in the string 'tmpgword'. 
that is true, and hence we go into the 'for-loop' again; and then into the 'if'-block ( the right char is found ) but here erase() don't work, and we enter in an infinite loop.

when the program finds the right index using 'for-loop', I break, and I start the search from the beginning in case there are more occurrences of guess.

the problem is: the program finds 'guess' again but erase() won't delete it!

can someone explain please. Here is my code:

```
while (tmpgword.find(guess,0) != string::npos )
        {
            for (i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) // verify the input; 
            {

                if (word[i] == guess)
                {
                    encword[i] = word[i];//I don't think this line is important
                    tmpgword.erase(tmpgword.begin() + i);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: After you erase the character from `tmpgword`, it's not equal to `word` any more. So the positions in `word` don't match the positions in `tmpgword`.

Comment: `.tmpgword.find()` returns the position of the character when it's found. Why don't you just put that in a variable and erase that position?

Comment: I made a mistake ==> I changed my code many times, I found a better solution but I wanted to know why this code is not working well; ( coding for more than 3 hours), I lost my concentration and I didn't recognize this mistake, thanks, I understand what's going on now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you do the first erase, the character positions in `tmpgword` are not the same as in `word`.

`string::find()` returns the position of the element when it's found, so you can use that instead of looping through `word`.

```
size_t pos = 0;
while ((pos = tmpgword.find(guess, pos)) != string::npos) {
    tmpgword.erase(pos, 1);
}
```

I've used `pos` as the starting position for each call to `find()` so it starts from where it just erased, rather than searching from the beginning each time through (there can't be any occurrences before that, because they've all been erased).

Comment: @Galik Thx. I hate using an editor without paren-matching.